# How to add a number of char on a string in python

Tags: python, string, char, addition

Hello is there a function that will get a string S and a number n and will add (n-1) # at the start and (n-1) % at the end. In python. I know how to add a char but not a number of them. Example S= abracatabra and n =3 result : ##abracatabra%%

Comment: `new_str = "{}{}{}".format((n - 1) * '#', S, (n - 1) * '%')`

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
string = "test"
n = 3
for i in range(1,n):
    string = "#"+string+"%"
print(string)
```

The version of @idjaw is better optimized that this solution but remember you can just add strings using +.

Alternative version:

```
string = "#"*(n-1)+string+"%"*(n-1)
```

Comment: Not quite, no. It's supposed to be (n - 1). Your final result will end up having three '#' and three '%'

Comment: @idjaw thnx for letting me know. fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved using Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language specification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=format%20mini#format-specification-mini-language). This allows pad characters and widths to be specified as follows:

```
n = 5
text = "abracatabra"

print "{:#>{w}}{}{:%>{w}}".format("", text, "", w=n-1)
```

This would display:

```
####abracatabra%%%%
```

In effect this is printing 3 items, firstly an empty string padded with `n-1` `#` fill characters. Secondly the `text` string. Lastly another empty string padded with `n-1` `%` fill characters.